# Repairing CentOS files permission

Tags: linux, centos

I've screwed my CentOS 6 server. I've ran chmod on a few symlinks and changed permissions important file such those in /bin and all commands even clear says Permission Denied.  Now It is unable to boot.

How do I restore permissions?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/a/469079/984 http://serverfault.com/questions/105957/accidently-ran-chown-www-datawww-data-r-as-root/106057#106057 http://serverfault.com/questions/403321/chmod-r-777-rhel-5-5

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, boot a live cd and grab a backup of the files you need. Then head to re-install town.... :(

You MIGHT be able to install over your broken version and only break a few [hundred] things...

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you've overly restricted a bunch of system directories. Before I tell you how to solve your immediate issue you should know that default permissions differ throughout and there's no simple way I can think of to recover this without backup recovery or some level of re-installation. The security and stability of the system may be seriously compromised.

1. Boot from some sort of Linux Live CD/USB
2. Mount your system partition.
3. Ensure bin/* is still owned by root.
4. Change bin/* permission to 755.
   Note: Permissions 755 makes the file readable and executable by *all*. I would certainly not do this in a directory like /etc or /var.